# get_search_form() and aria_label

Tags: theme-development, accessibility

How do you pass the aria_label parameter to get_search_form()?

I can't seem to pass the 'aria_label' parameter to get_search_form() in the correct way and can't find any examples. Lots with the first parameter 'echo' which works as in the documentation, but nothing I've tried for aria_label has made the search form add aria labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array of attributes with `aria_label` attribute in it. 
Try this:

```
get_search_form(array('aria_label' => 'search-form'));
```

This function gets a form from `searchform.php` by default and if you have this file in your theme and aria-label still missing, you need to check the code in this file. Sometimes developers do not include an option to set an aria-label.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this similar issue, and was able to resolve in my `searchform.php` by adding this to my `form` tag:

```
<form aria-label="<?php echo $args['aria_label']; ?>">...</form>
```

This produces the output of what was passed into the `aria_label` item in the arguments array.

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 5.5 we have been able to pass data into template files and use that data in the template from the `$args` array.  This was a "long awaited addition" according to the article.

You can read more about this here https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/ and this goes along with the info @toby-dawes gave above.

This is super powerful and I have been using this in my custom themes since it was added.  Love it!